# Form load freezes when setting Stylemanager.ManagerColorTint

Tags: vb.net, winforms, form-load

When my `foarload` event method fires, I then have

```
Try 
    '//this is the default or modified color tint
    StyleManager1.ManagerColorTint = ColorTint
Catch ex As Exception
End Try
```

it gets to the `StyleManager1.ManagerColorTint = ColorTint`
and then when I continue it just freezes,

`StyleManager1`  is `DevComponents.DotNetBar.StyleManager`

Currently `stylemanager1.managercolortint` is 255, 50, 50, 50
as is `ColorTint`.

If I put a breakpoint on this line, it still freezes, unless I bypass that line, then it all runs great.

If it hits that line again it freezes still.

Anybody got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... maybe under the catch ex as Exception line, try to print something out, e.g. msgbox("Error") to see if it gets there, even though you say it freezes.

I hope this helps, if not i apologize and gl.